# Save CURRENT_TIMESTAMP include millisecond SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, timestamp, dynamic-sql

I have a store procedure. When this sp execute, I want to save start time and end time in my database. So, I use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to get current time with millisecond. But, when I use a dynamic query to update my table like:

```
Set @query = 'Update Table1 set startTime='''+CURRENT_TIMESTAMP+''' where '+@Condition
EXEC(@query)
```

I got this error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

So, I change my code to:

```
Set @query = 'Update Table1 set startTime='''+CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as varchar(100))+''' where '+@Condition
EXEC(@query)
```

Now, it execute success but the result doesn't contain millisecond. How to save the result include millisecond?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first query, you get an error because you're trying to add a string to a date.

Try this

```
 set @query = 'Update Table1 set startTime=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where ' + @condition
```